# Lenovo TP X230 + Series 3 Docking - Toggle between DVI and DP working?

Tags: thinkpad, dvi, displayport, docking

Hi,

Is anyone using DVI and DP of the Series 3 Docking with Ubuntu?

For now I'm using DVI for my monitor and I plan to use DP to connect to my TV (DP -> HDMI -> TV).

**Lenovo** says it isn't possible to use DVI and DP simultaneous, but is it possible (and working with ubuntu 13.10) to switch between DVI and DP within the running system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried it now and it works. Audio and Video. And they are also working simultaneous.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, it only allows two displays. Three aren't possible due to Intel graphics restrictions, although the sum of the displays are not higher than the allowed resolution at least here.

Comment: +1 because likely relevant answer. Quick googling points to [this Lenovo documentation](https://support.lenovo.com/documents/pd029622), which explains on different display and video output configurations. Although X230 model is unlisted, X240 and X250 have similar limitations.